# WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-mapping

I developed a java desktop application using hibernate to connect to my computer's mysql database.

When I run the application on the computer that is the mysql server, it works properly, but when I run it from another computer to connect, I get the error:
`WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure`

This is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"     
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.72:3306/factura_registro?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1</property>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
         <property name="show_sql">false</property>
         <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my `main class`

```
public class App {
    public static Configuration c;
    public static ServiceRegistry reg;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {   


try {
        c= new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Usuario.class).addAnnotatedClass(Unidad.class);
        reg= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(c.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sf= c.buildSessionFactory(reg);
        Session s= sf.openSession();
        //-------------Comenzar interface inicio sesion--------------//
        final Dao dao = new Dao(s);
          
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUIInicioSesion sesion =new GUIInicioSesion(dao);
                sesion.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                sesion.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error", "Alerta", 2);
    }
    }    
}
```

These are de messages

[Starting configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Etc.png)

[Warning show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmbU3.png)

[Exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZZA.png)

Comment: Most likely the computer running MySQL does not allow connections from external hosts. It could be a firewall rule, or the IP address that the MySQL server is configured to bind to.

Comment: It was for the firewall, thank you